# Change checkbox Icon in Yii2

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

How can I change the checkbox icon when it's checked in Yii2?
For now, I add checkbox in the div and inside it, I add an icon:`<i class="fa fa-check-circle icon-check-circle"></i>` but it shows the checkbox check symbol how can I change it to my preferred icon? Thanks.

```php
<div class="box-div-buttontoadd">
    <i class="fa fa-check-circle icon-check-circle"></i>
    <div class="div_row buttons hidden-xs">
        <?= $form->field($model,'addedToCard')->checkbox([
            'id' => 'products-addedtocard-'. $model->id,
            'class' => 'addedtocard-chk'
        ]); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to use font awesome icon instead of checkbox tick symbol?

Comment: what exact html you are trying to follow for the check box, do you have any live link of the example checkbox you are talking about. so we can see the html structure or layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to change icon with CSS, there is a plenty examples like [this](https://codepen.io/jamesbarnett/pen/yILjk) 
Just don't forget to use the element class what is `.addedtocard-chk` in your example, or just the simple `input[type="checkbox"]`. Be sure to get the FontAwesome CSS and place it in your project folder.